# Refactoring WCF service client instantiation from app.config to code

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service reference which I use with the following client side app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ManagerService">
                <security>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://myadress:8080/ManagerService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ManagerService"
            contract="Service.ManagerService" name="WSHttpBinding_ManagerService">
            <identity>
                <certificate encodedValue="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" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I now need to refactor the instantiation to work with a blank app.config:

Here is what I've tried:

```
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Security = new WSHttpSecurity { Mode = SecurityMode.Message };
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;            
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var cers = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "123THUMBPRINTOFCERT", false);
var cer = cers[0];
var identity = new X509CertificateEndpointIdentity(cer);
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://myservice:8080/ManagerService.svc"), identity);
var client = new ManagerServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = EMail;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;
var resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
var categories = client.Categorize(Text);
```

This throws an exception:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: Client cannot
>   determine the Service Principal Name based on the identity in the
>   target address 'http://myservice:8080/ManagerService.svc' for
>   the purpose of SspiNegotiation/Kerberos. The target address identity
>   must be a UPN identity (like acmedomain\alice) or SPN identity (like
>   host/bobs-machine).

I have checked, that the correct certificate is found in the store. I would be very glad to get a hint on what I am missing here and whether the way I'm going here is ok in general...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you lost row `clientCredentialType="UserName"`

```
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! I've added the line (I've updated the question as well), unfortunately I still get the same exception. Do you see anything else missing here?

Comment: You got it almost... I was missing:  binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName; Thanks for your help, would have been a hard one to find without your hint!! I've edited your answer and hope, you're cool with that ;)